# Problems using jQuery selector "nth-of-type"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code for a family tree layout.  I am trying to get the number of persons in each 'div.d3' using 'nth-of-type' and targeting the 'a' tag.
Results are 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 instead of 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2.

```js
for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) { // FOR EACH CHILD
  var num = $('.d3:nth-of-type(' + (j + 1) + ') a').size();
  console.log(j + ' = ' + num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
  <div class='row d d3' id='c0' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(7)">
      <div class="content f" id="d30">Leila Rose<br><b>JONES</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2009 - </span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(8)">
      <div class="content m" id="d31">Oscar<br><b>JONES</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2012 - </span></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
  <div class='row d d3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class='row d d3' id='c2' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(26)">
      <div class="content f" id="d32">Natasha<br><b>SMITH</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2007 - </span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(27)">
      <div class="content m" id="d33">Gabriel<br><b>SMITH</b><br><span class="nee"><br>1997 - </span></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(3, auto);'>
  <div class='row d d3' id='c3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(25)">
      <div class="content f" id="d34">Karen<br><b>WILLIAMS</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2010 - </span></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='row d d3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class='row d d3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
  <div class='row d d3' id='c6' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(33)">
      <div class="content f" id="d35">Child1<br><b>WILSON</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2001 - </span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(34)">
      <div class="content m" id="d36">Child2<br><b>WILSON</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2003 - </span></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='row d d3' id='c7' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(31)">
      <div class="content f" id="d37">Penelopy "Penny"<br><b>TAYLOR</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2007 - </span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="getBase(32)">
      <div class="content f" id="d38">Claire<br><b>TAYLOR</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2012 - </span></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jQuery code is in a `<script>` at the bottom.

Comment: Your answer code works OK in the snippet, but does not show the index or the zero for empty divs with no 'a' tags in the actual code.  Any suggestions?

Comment: SilentCoder's snippet (and also my answer) logs 8 numbers which is equal to the number of div's with the 'd3' class. That includes the first div in the second row which is an empty div. Is that not what you wanted? Perhaps you should update your answer to allow us to reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `nth-of-type` for your requirement.

```js
var d3Items  = $('.d3');
var i = 0;


d3Items.each(function(){
 var aCount = $(this).find('a').length;
   console.log(i + ' = ' + aCount);
 i++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
    <div class='row d d3' id='c0' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(7)"><div class="content f" id="d30">Leila Rose<br><b>JONES</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2009 - </span></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(8)"><div class="content m" id="d31">Oscar<br><b>JONES</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2012 - </span></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
    <div class='row d d3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row d d3' id='c2' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(26)"><div class="content f" id="d32">Natasha<br><b>SMITH</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2007 - </span></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(27)"><div class="content m" id="d33">Gabriel<br><b>SMITH</b><br><span class="nee"><br>1997 - </span></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(3, auto);'>
    <div class='row d d3' id='c3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(25)"><div class="content f" id="d34">Karen<br><b>WILLIAMS</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2010 - </span></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class='row d d3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
        <div></div>
    </div>
     <div class='row d d3' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(1, auto);'>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row d' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
    <div class='row d d3' id='c6' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(33)"><div class="content f" id="d35">Child1<br><b>WILSON</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2001 - </span></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(34)"><div class="content m" id="d36">Child2<br><b>WILSON</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2003 - </span></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class='row d d3' id='c7' style='grid-template-columns:repeat(2, auto);'>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(31)"><div class="content f" id="d37">Penelopy "Penny"<br><b>TAYLOR</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2007 - </span></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="getBase(32)"><div class="content f" id="d38">Claire<br><b>TAYLOR</b><br><span class="nee"><br>2012 - </span></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, SilentCoder, but I am not getting the zeros.

Comment: did you run my code snippet? it shows 0 there. so it because you've changed you `html` structure. is the provided code is up to date ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$('.d3').each(function(i) {
  console.log(i + ' = ', $(this).find('a').length);
});
```

https://codepen.io/rockysims/pen/oaJrGQ

The issue is that `nth-of-type(n)` is selecting the `n`th child div matching '.d3' in each parent div (the 'row' divs). So `nth-of-type(1)` is selecting #c0, (a div without an id), #c3, and #c6 then getting all the `a` tags in those divs (2 from #c0, 0 from div without id, 1 from #c3, and 2 from #c6 for a total of 5). That's why the first number you're seeing is 5.

Comment: Same as SilentCoder above - this does not give me the zeros.

Comment: Yes it does... I've added a codepen.io link to my answer so you can see for yourself. The zeros are there.